# docker-compose phpmyadmin kicks out

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose

I'm trying to use a docker-compose.yml for launching `mariabd` and `phpmyadmin`. When I edit something on `phpmyadmin` it kicks me out to login page.

```
db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Pass123
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql/:rw"
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  links:
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8181:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Pass123
    PMA_HOST: mysql
```

I've tried with a volume container with `busybox` to keep data of `mysql`, changed `mariabd` for `mysql` image. But I don't get with the solution. What should I do to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of environmental variables supported by the `phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin` Docker image is different from that of the `mariadb` image. Try replacing the `MYSQL_USERNAME` and `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` variables of your `phpmyadmin` service with `PMA_USER` and `PMA_PASSWORD`, respectively.

Comment: With those variables `phpmyadmin` is working nice now, but is logging automatically without asking user/password. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Take a look at [this section](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#securing-your-phpmyadmin-installation) in the phpmyadmin doc. In particular, one of the points gives information on hiding your phpmyadmin behind an authentication proxy.

Comment: @berzas Please consider accepting the answer if it answered your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the meaning of the link

```
links:
- db:mysql
```

The configuration file of phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin (/www/config.inc.php) say by default the host name of database server if 'db' :

```
$hosts = array('db');
```

As you name the database server 'db' then link should be write likez this :

```
links:
- db
```

If your database name container is not 'db', you should add the environment variable PMA_HOST= (or PMA_HOSTS if multi db servers) with the right name

All over environment variables are useless (even in db config I think)